# Detect rectangle from array of points C#

Tags: c#, image-processing, aforge, imaging

I'm having a picture, and an array of points from within the picture.

Some points are close to each other, some don't have any 'neighbours'. I'm looking for a way to find the sub-image which is formed by the points that have many neighbours, eventually with a given maximum distance between them.

Here's an example:

[image]

As you can see in the image, there are multiple points, some are close, some don't have any close neighbours. I want to find a rectangle which is located by checking the *spot* in the image, where multiple points are in a very close range. It's always going to be a rectangle, and there could be multiple rectangles/spots in the same image.

I'm using the AForge (C#) library for some image processing. Searched for algorithms that do this, but haven't found much. I'm pretty sure there is an algorithm for this exact purpose, I just haven't found it yet.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: This isn't an imaging problem, it's a *geometry* problem. You won't find the solution in image processing libraries

Comment: Also note that clustering is *not* NP complete. There are a *lot* of clustering algorithms that may or may not find an optimal solution

Answer (score 2):

I dont't know the AForge library, but if you don't have many points (like in the example), a simple nearest neighborhood search algorithm would be just fine i guess.

- Basically you just pick a point and try to find its neighbors within a threshold.
- These neighbors have to be stored in some sort of data structure (e.g. an array). If there are no more neighbors, repeat the search starting from a found neighbor and so on.
- Finally you will have a set of neighborhoods where you just pick the largest set (the set with the most points).
- Then just compute a rectangle around these points (corner points).

Assuming that the majority of points are located within the rectangle you are looking for, you could just calculate a "center point" of all points (average). Starting from this point, you look for the closest point you have and start your nearest neighbor search from there. In this case, you will have only one set of points where you can again build the rectangle around.

Comment: This is a geometry problem. AForge is an imaging library, which has nothing to do with geometry. This particular problem though is primarily about *clustering*.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
In general, I'm going to have around 50 points/image.
The thing I'm not sure about are the corner points, but looks like google has some info for that.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for the suggestion, but I think all the imaging libraries have something to do with geometry :P

Comment: @user1812076 look for clustering algorithms. This has nothing at all to do with images. There are a *lot* of clustering algorithms though because this isn't an easy problem to solve.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Not looking for the easiest solution, don't care VERY much about speed, just need something that does it.

Comment: @user1812076 then you are wrong. None of them have any spatial or clustering algorithms. None of them calculates distances, neighbours etc. That's spatial, GIS *and* AI territory.

Comment: What do you mean you are not sure with the corner points? When you got your cluster of points, you just have to look for the lowest and highest values in each x- and y-dimension -> this will give you the surrounding rectangle.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I might be wrong ... not sure how aforge works at it's core. I'm just saying that in my oppinion, imaging has something to do with geometry :P

Comment: @ThomasD. not really ... I might have 2 sub-images/rectangles in the same image

Comment: @user1812076 oh i see. Then you will need (as others have already said) a clustering algorithm (a simple one would be "k-means") to get multiple clusters. From these clusters, you can then easily get the rectangles.

Comment: There won't be more than 2-3 rectangles for sure, 85% of the time just one rectangle. I think you mean the minimum empty space between them, but I'm not very sure ... but I would say ~150px

Comment: @user1812076 I am not sure where you are stuck at? DId you take a look at clustering algorithms?